How is this question on the Puzzling SE not trivial?
Link to question

Grandmaster Lev Alburt plays at least one game of chess a day to keep in shape and not more than 10 games in any consecutive seven-day period to avoid tiring himself out. Is it true that if he plays long enough there will be a series of consecutive days during which he will play exactly 23 games?

As of time of writing, the question has attracted several answers that look (to me) fairly complicated. The first one that leaps to my mind is that the question is nearly trivial. Because of the infinite monkey theorem, as long as there is any chance that Grandmaster Lev Alburt plays 23 games over a series of consecutive days, then "if he plays long enough" it is guaranteed to happen. And it's obvious that there is a nonzero chance that he will do so: he can play one game per day for 23 consecutive days (i.e., we don't need to consider him playing more than one game a day). Even if the question were modified to say "Grandmaster Lev Alburt plays 2 games a day with 99.99% probability and 1 game a day with 0.01% probability ...", it's still true that if he plays long enough there will be 23 consecutive days during which he plays exactly 1 game per day.
I am wondering if I am missing someting.

The question would be trivial if we assumed that the grandmaster acts probabilistically.

Infinite monkey theorem says "almost surely", not "with certainty". Just because something has an "almost surely" (probability $1$) chance of happening, does not mean that it will ceratinly happen. For example, if I keep tossing a coin, I will "almost surely" get at least one Tail, i.e. the probability that I will get at least one tail is $1.$ But it is possible that I get no tails if I keep flipping forever. In other words, it is possible for a probability $0$ event to occur, and it is possible for a probability $1$ event to not occur.

But Lev might be deliberately playing numbers of games such that he avoids any span of consecutive days with 23 games played. He's not asking a monkey to choose for him how many games he'll play a day.

@JamieRadcliffe I see, suggest writing that as an answer.

If for example the limit was not more than $10$ games in a $5$ day rolling window (rather than $7$) , he might play $2$ each day for his whole life, so the sum over any number of consecutive days would be even and so never $23$.

You misinterpreted the infinite monkey theorem.

The GM is not choosing randomly (within specific constraints) how many game(s) to play on a given day. He gets to choose how many game(s) he plays on a day. As long as it is at least one, and as long as he maintains a running total of at most 10 over a 7 day rolling window, he has satisfied the required constraints. Now think of it in game theoretic terms. Can the GM devise a strategy to play his games in such a way that he will not total exactly 23 games in any consecutive rolling window (which obviously has to be at most 23 days long)? If he can't, prove it.
